# Automatically start a program at Raspbian - Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, linux, embedded-linux, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian distribution.

I've written a script in Python 3 and I would need to start it up automatically just when system boots up, without logging in.

Comment: is it the rc script? you have to paste your script what you have written in-order to know why your program is not started at start?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) to achieve this. Take for example your python script is called hello.py.

1. Create a systemd service file at `/lib/systemd/system/hello.service`:

   ```
   [Unit]

   Description=hello.py service file
   After=multi-user.target

   [Service]
   Type=simple
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /dir/to/your/hello.py
   Restart=always

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

The full list of commands and functions for the systemd service file can be found [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html).

2. Add appropriate permissions to the .service file: `sudo chmod 644 /lib/systemd/system/hello.service`
3. Reload the systemd daemon: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
4. Enable the hello systemd service: `sudo systemctl enable hello.service`

You can check that your service is running by using the command: `sudo systemctl status hello.service` and check for any errors using `sudo journalctl`

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry PI has quite good support. Tasks can be schedualed with usage of "crontab" command.

You can find documentation on: [Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md)

Within this documentation you have example for running "python" script on Raspberry Pi reboot.

Hope it helps!